# Combining forms Powershell

Tags: forms, powershell, user-input

Currently I have 3 forms which asks a user for some form of input.
First it asks a first name, then last name and last it asks the user to select from a list of functions.
However I was wondering if I could combine all of these into 1 single form and single prompt instead of people getting pop ups the whole time.

So instead of 3 times a prompt for input, it would be inserted in 1 prompt and I would extract the data from there.

So basically I'm wondering if there's a way to combine multiple forms into a single form for ease of use or if that's impossible in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible tu use a WPF XAML user interface.
First you need to build the user interface (.xaml file) with either Visual Studio or a text editor.

MainWindow.xaml :

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Functions" Height="230" Width="420">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Label Content="First Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Height="23"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="23" Margin="0,30,30,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Height="23"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="LastNameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="23" Margin="0,65,30,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170"/>
        <Label Content="Function" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Height="23"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="FunctionComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,100,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Height="23" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="function1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="168"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="function2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="168"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name="SubmitButton" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,120,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then you can display this user interface and process user input with the following PowerShell script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

function Load-XamlFile( $path )
{
    Write-Host "Loading XAML file $path..."
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xml = Get-Content -Path $path
    $xmlReader = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $xml
    $xaml = [System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $xmlReader )
    return $xaml
}

# Main Window
$MainWindow = Load-XamlFile 'MainWindow.xaml'

# Getting window elements
$FirstNameTextBox = $MainWindow.FindName('FirstNameTextBox')
$LastNameTextBox = $MainWindow.FindName('LastNameTextBox')
$FunctionComboBox = $MainWindow.FindName('FunctionComboBox')
$SubmitButton = $MainWindow.FindName('SubmitButton')

# Script block launched when the Submit button is clicked
$SubmitButton.Add_Click({

    $FirstName = $FirstNameTextBox.Text
    $LastName =  $LastNameTextBox.Text
    $Function = $FunctionComboBox.Text

    # Do whatever you need with the user input

})

# Display GUI
$MainWindow.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```